# Qualtrics and Javascript - Randomly insert words into sentences

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I carry out a study in which I present different sentences (one per page).

I would like to insert randomly words in those sentences.

Each participant sees the sentences in the same order. Only one word in each of the sentences have to be randomly presented.

For example :

-Hello [insert one of the 8 words] i like dogs.

-Hello [insert one of the 7 remaining words] i like birds.

-Hi [insert one of the 6 remaining words] i like cats.

etc.

I think I have to use Javascript and I don't know how to do it, but maybe there is a simpler solution.

Thank you for your help and have a nice day !
(Sorry if there are mistakes, English is not my native langage).

**Edit :**

Actually, someone suggested a code on the Qualtrics forum that apparently works but I think there's something wrong with it because it's not working.

Here is the code :

```
function shuffle(array) {
var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

// While there remain elements to shuffle...
while (0 !== currentIndex) {

// Pick a remaining element...
randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
currentIndex -= 1;

// And swap it with the current element.
temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
}

return array;
}

Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
let names = ["Jennifer", "Jessica", "Amanda", "Ashley", "Sarah", "Stephanie", "Melissa", "Nicole", "Elizabeth", 
                            "Heather", "Tiffany", "Michelle", "Amber", "Megan", "Amy", "Rachel", "Kimberly", "Christina", 
                            "Lauren", "Crystal", "Michael", "Chris", "Matt", "Josh", "David", "James", "Daniel",
                            "Robert", "John", "Joe", "Jason", "Justin", "Andrew", "Ryan", "William", "Brian", "Brandon", "Jon",
                            "Nick", "Tony", "Eric", "Adam", "Kevin", "Tom", "Steve", "Tim", "Richard", "Jeremy", "Jeff", "Kyle"];
shuffle(names);
for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++)  {
    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addEmbeddedData("name"+i, names[i]);
}
});
```

Comment: Usually it is helpful to see a code example of what you have tried, but your question is clear enough to me to answer.

Answer (score -1):

Hi this is a basic approach to start on.

```js
const quotes = [
  "Hello $, I like dogs.",
  "Hello $, I like cats.",
  "Hello $, I like doing my homework on my own and not asking for solutions on SO.",
]
const names = ["B.stb", "Donald", "Julia"];


for (let quote of quotes) {
  let name = names.splice(names.length * Math.random() | 0, 1)[0]
  console.log(quote.replace(/\$/g, name));
}
```